# Insecure content for HTTPS - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

i have a problem with the platform and ssl certificate. The certificate is installed and all the links are https, and any browser says that "this site has insecure content.... like images" but all the images are with https.
https://pheonixsecurity.ro/ this is the website.

Comment: Have you checked the Console? It seems some images has been missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logo is loaded from `'http://pheonixsecurity.ro/beta/wp-content/themes/bridge/img/logo.png'` it's not https.

See the capture:
[image]

You can verify it from your admin side or check in database if the site url has `https` by default so that all resources from it may be loaded from `https` source.

Comment: Thanks bro. That was helpful.

Comment: Great. so consider to accept the answer  please to help future readers.